# Extracting first name, last name, phone number, and address from a form

Tags: c#, validation, form

I have this:

```
public void InfoAssignment()
{
    //MessageBox.Show(firstName = firstNameBox.Text);
    firstName = firstNameBox.Text;
    lastName = lastNameBox.Text;
    phoneNumber = phoneBox.Text;
    address = addressBox.Text;

    //Check for text in firstNameBox
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstName))
    {
        firstName = firstNameBox.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a first name");
        return;
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastName))
    {
        lastName = lastNameBox.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a last name");
        return;
    }

    if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(phoneNumber))
    {
        phoneNumber = phoneBox.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a phone number");
        return;
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(address))
    {
        address = addressBox.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a phone number");
        return;
    }
    //firstName = firstNameBox.Text;
    //lastName = lastNameBox.Text;
}
```

It does what I need it to do but obviously this is basically repeating the same thing with only minor variations. I'm thinking there has to be a better way of which I'm unaware. Is there?

Comment: You can do your checks directly on the textbox values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

Pass the variables by reference and let the method update them if the input is valid.

Do processing if all the inputs are valid.

EDIT: I needed to change the method name from `ValidateInput` to `CopyToVariableWithValidation` because the former fails to have a good name to represent it's function.

```
private bool CopyToVariableWithValidation(TextBox textBox, string inputFriendlyName, ref string variableToCopyContent)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a " + inputFriendlyName);
        return false;
    }
    variableToCopyContent = textBox.Text;
    return true;
}

public void InfoAssignment()
{
    if
    (
        CopyToVariableWithValidation(firstNameBox, "First Name", ref firstName) &&
        CopyToVariableWithValidation(lastNameBox, "Last Name", ref lastName) &&
        CopyToVariableWithValidation(phoneBox, "Phone Number", ref phoneNumber) &&
        CopyToVariableWithValidation(addressBox, "Address", ref address)
    )
    {
        // Input is valid. Do more processing here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could create a method for it!

```
bool Validate(string val, TextBox textBox, string description)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val))
    {
        val = textBox.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter " + description");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Then you could use it like so:

```
if (!Validate(firstName, firstNameBox, "a first name"))
   return;
if (!Validate(lastName, lastNameBox, "a last name"))
   return;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a copy-and-paste error: it does `MessageBox.Show("Please enter a phone number");` when the address is missing.